# Why is my FlaskForm submitted automatically?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I made a web app using python, flask and wtforms. I added a new form with the single purpose of calling a function in my .py file on click/submit.
Problem: when running the app and rendering the template, the form is submitted automatically (without me clicking the submit-button in my browser). I mean as soon as I browse the html, `button.is_submitted()` is True and the function is called.
What am I missing?

EDIT: I have another form in the same `example.html` maybe that is the cause? I tried the code below and it worked just fine, but as soon as there are more forms the problem recurs.

in app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "not_so_secret"

class call_button(FlaskForm):
  submit = SubmitField("call function!")

def function():
  print("hi") 

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def example():
  
  button1 = call_button()

  if button1.validate_on_submit():
    function()

  return render_template("example.html",template_button_1 = button1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, threaded=True)
```

in example.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div>
<form method="POST">
{{ template_button_1.hidden_tag() }}
{{ template_button_1.submit() }}
</form> 
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Would you mind also sharing the nonworking code so that others can reproduce your problem?

Comment: `{{ template_button_1.submit() }}` I think this is the reason.  You're telling the template to submit the button immediately.